# × Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.[ReactJS]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

am trying to build an Application using ReactJS but am getting this "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app"

I tried many method from Google but i won't worked still getting this error.
Please help me!

**CODE**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useHistory, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

function ProductDetails() {
  const { id } = useParams()
  // const { setText } = props;
  console.log(id)
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{id}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductDetails
```

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import Header from './Components/Header';
import Homepage from './Components/HomePage';
import CartDetails from './Components/CartDetails';
import ProductDetails from './Components/ProductDetails';
import Error404 from './Components/Error404';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState(0);
 
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Header text={text}/>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
          <Route exact path="/cart-details" component={()=> <CartDetails val={text} />} />
          <Route exact path="/products-details/:id" component={ProductDetails} />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/products-details/:id"
            component={() => <ProductDetails setText={setText} />}
          />
          
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>

    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

package.json

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=16.8.0",
    "react-dom": ">=16.8.0"
 },
```

```
 "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
```

Comment: How do you use `App`?

Comment: want to use useParams() to get url parameter ID. but not working.. please help me

Comment: No. Re-read my question. How do you use `App`? You're probably doing `ReactDOM.render(App, ...)` which is wrong, and instead you need to do `ReactDOM.render(<App />, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

you should put a parameter called `props` in the `ProductDetails()` component then only you can access the props from the parent component. 
put like this

```
function ProductDetails(props) {
   const { setText } = props;
   ....
}
```

Now you can use `setText` function inside the `ProductDetails` component.

Comment: Sir I don't want it..I want to use useParams() to get url parameter ID. But In my case it's not working